# Summernote display format

Tags: summernote

> Summernote table border not showing and following the correct format

[image: Summernote table border not showing and following the correct format]

> and this is what i get

[image: and this is what i get]

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when creating table summernote adds class="table table bordered" and not saving it

Comment: is there a way to fix it? ran into the same problem.